# Setting Multimeda keys and volume knob on Dell Mutlimedia Keyboard using KeyRemap4MacBook?

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook, keymap

I have plugged in a dell multimedia keyboard with my macbook and I am using the software KeyRemap4MacBook to change some keys on the external keyboard.

However I cannot setup the multimedia keys like (next,previous) and also the volume knob.

Has anyone tried this before ?

Comment: It worked with my Kinesis Advantage. Have you tried [using private.xml](http://superuser.com/questions/403493/kinesis-advantage-os-x-media-keys/529315#529315)?