# Something intercepting my Fn keys for 1 of 2 keyboards

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

Running Windows 10 on a Dell 7040. Have two USB keyboards hanging off the device. One is a Dell keyboard, the other an Kinesis Advantage Contour.

Everything was fine on both until last week when the function keys on Kinesis started getting intercepted to control volume up (F10), volumen down (F11), etc. The Dell keyboard is fine.

I'd assumed I activated function lock on the Kinesis, but as far as I can tell its not supported. I reset the keyboard to factory settings just in case, but no change.

Fn F10 on the Dell keyboard doesn't control volume. (It has the "Play Previous" icon "|<<" ).

It's possible I installed an app that has this "feature" but haven't been able to locate it.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Turns out it was a feature of the Kenisis keyboard. Answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/403493/kinesis-advantage-os-x-media-keys